# Check user is Admin at login

Tags: php, mysql, login-script

I have a login script so that users can log in my website, my question is that when an Admin logs in it will include a admin page using the PHP function include.

My problem is that I need some advise as to how to check the session to see if the user is an Admin and if so include the Admin page.

Any help would be fantastic.

```
<?php

ob_start();
$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:staff_portal/index.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: How are you saving whether they are an admin or not?  How do you know if they are an admin?

Comment: Without any code example, advice will be extremely difficult... Update your question please

Comment: In the database there is a column called admin which is either 0 or 1. 1 being admin.

Comment: So, where are you stuck?  Just include that row in your SQL query, and check `if($admin == 1)` in your page.

Comment: How old is this code?!  [`session_register`](http://php.net/session_register) has been *deprecated* since PHP 5.3 (and removed in 5.4)!  You should use `$_SESSION["myusername"] = $myusername;`.  P.S. I also suggest switching from the (also deprecated) `mysql_*` functions and PDO or MySQLi (more info: http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Comment: What  user type you given for Admin.?

Answer (score 1):

If `$row` contains the array of data from the database...

```
$admin = $row["admin"]==1 ? true : false;

if($admin){
    //do admin stuff
}

if(!$admin){
    //don't show this stuff to the admin
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once they log in, you need to check whether or not their profile has `0` or `1` for the `admin` column.

Seems you want to use `sessions` so something like this might work:

```
if ($_SESSION['admin']) {
    // Show admin page
}
```

Where you would need to set `$_SESSION['admin']` depending on their log in credentials.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to register it in the session at the point the user logged on?

Comment: When approaching this way, yes.